Rust debugging in VS Code Windows Aarch64 or Arm64ec
Attempting to debug rust with VS Code on a windows pc with Qualcomm Snapdragon X1 Elite X1E-78 results in error This platform (win32-arm64) is not supported. Adding the screenshot here since it's not clear what process is originating the message:

How does one repath VS Code and the extensions in windows on snapdragon to the use the correct aach64-pc-windows-msvc toolchain components, in order to enable IntelliSense and debugging?
Confirmed target, nightly toolchain, rust-analyzer install
PS C:\Users\User.Name> rustup target list
aarch64-apple-darwin
...
aarch64-pc-windows-msvc (installed)
...
arm64ec-pc-windows-msvc (installed)

PS C:\Users\User.Name> rustup toolchain list
stable-aarch64-pc-windows-msvc
nightly-aarch64-pc-windows-msvc (default)

PS C:\Users\User.Name> rustup component add rust-analyzer
info: component 'rust-analyzer' for target 'aarch64-pc-windows-msvc' is up to date

.vscode/launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Cargo launch",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "--bin gltf-converter",
                    "--target aarch64-pc-windows-msvc"
                ]
            },
            "args": [
                ""
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Hardware and Software Details



Component
Version
Details




Snapdragon(TM) X Elite
X1E78100
Qualcomm(TM) Oryon(TM) CPU 3.42 GHz


Windows 11 Enterprise
24H2
26100.2605


rustup
1.27.1
(54dd3d00f 2024-04-24)


rustc
1.83.0
(90b35a623 2024-11-26)


Visual Studio Code
1.96
138f619


rust-analyzer Extension
v0.3.2212
rust-lang.rust-analyzer


CodeLLDB Extension
v1.11.1
vadimcn.vscode-lldb


rust Extension
1.0.0
1yib.rust-bundle



